# The way of configuration for XA ContainerManagedTransaction in EJB

Tags: java, transactions, ejb

I've succeeded to create a Bean Managed Transaction sample and it works.
I set up two programs that A Java program calls B C++ program, and each program has own transaction.

The only thing I had to do was

> 1. "@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
> 2. UserTransaction tx = this.ejbContext.getUserTransaction()
> 3. tx.begin();
> 4. tx.commit(); OR tx.rollback();

However, when I wanted to use ContainerManagedTransaction with "TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER" and removed all the above methods and classes.. but it doesn't work.
So, I've tried to use "TransactionAttributeType.MANDATORY", it gives an error..like

> EJB Exception : "global tx required"
>   at com.ibm.ejs.csi.Mandatory.preInvoke(Mandatory.java:47)
>   ...

Could you give me a sample or a guidance to follow how to configure XA transaction in ContainerManagedTransaction?

Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use another annotation, REQUIRED or REQUIRES_NEW to make it work.

MANDATORY needs some transactional context coming from calling method, so can not be used to begin a new transaction.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
I've done it before and know it works.. but I need to add the several transaction to the global transaction..
If I use just REQUIRED, then the global transaction doesn't work.. Could you let me know where I have to put the @REQUIRED?

Comment: What are these several transactions? Can you please describe the new case more detailed? As an update to the question, or as a new question.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I succeeded and knew how to do it.